# Why did I get error with array using implode?

Tags: php

everyone. Have a problem. I have an array:

```
Array ( [('1', 'Enter the name')] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
```

But when I am trying to use implode(), I get an error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

This is my code:

```
  $sql = implode(',', $arraySpecial);
```

I read a few stackoverflow's themes about this problem and tried to write `$arraySpecial[0]`, but that didn't help me. And I got 2 errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: `Array ( [('1', 'Enter the name')] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )` That looks like gibberish.

Comment: please show how you define this "array". And how you get php to produce that output!?

Comment: and the error indicates that `$arraySpecial[0]` is an array, where it should be string or int.

Comment: Almost gibberish, but reproducible: https://3v4l.org/fp54r  problem is imploding the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `Array ( [('1', 'Enter the name')] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )` but assuming I am interpreting this correctly then you have an array inside of an array.

As `implode()` is looping through your array elements it encounters a sub-array and tries to append it into the string which it is building and PHP does not allow that.

You can reproduce this error with `$string = array().',';`